# Set state data receive from action in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm calling an action in componentDidMount as follows

```
componentDidMount() {
     const { allowedEvcCards} = this.props;
     allowedEvcCards(id);
}
```

With these actions i'm doing API calls and receiving some data as the response. I have set the data to a state with my reducer. I want to do some logic in the componentDidMount it self with the data received in the response.

For example in my reducer i'm doing this

```
case ALLOWED_EVC_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                allowedEvc: action.data
 }
```

And in `componentDidMount` i want to use `allowedEvc` . But it returns undefined as the action call is not complete at the time.

My action

```
// Get allowed Evc cards

export const ALLOWED_EVC_LOADING = 'ALLOWED_EVC_LOADING';
export const ALLOWED_EVC_SUCCESS = 'ALLOWED_EVC_SUCCESS';

export function allowedEvcCardsLoading() {
    return {
        type: ALLOWED_EVC_LOADING
    }
}

export function allowedEvcCardsSuccess(data) {
    return {
        type: ALLOWED_EVC_SUCCESS,
        data
    }
}

export function allowedEvcCards(id) {

    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(allowedEvcCardsLoading());

        axios.get(`${API_URL}/****/****/${id}/*****`, {
            headers: {
                // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log("Allowed EVC response ", res.data);
                if (res.data.success === true) {
                    dispatch(allowedEvcCardsSuccess(res.data));
                } else {
                    console.log("error");
                    // alert("error");
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use  connect for accessing reducer  values?

Comment: I'm using connect. But my state returns undefined as the action is not complete yet

Comment: Can i know which middleware you are using?  where your api call written?

Comment: middleware is redux thunk. Using axios to do my API calls.

Comment: @PrakashT i've included my action in the question

Comment: Did you write componentDidUpdate function?, Can you share your render page?

Comment: Since you're using axios you can use async/await to run the axios request, do something with the data and then call the action to update the state. If you need to do something before passing the data to the store, doing it in the action creator is not the best option, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `componentDidMount` is only called when a component is mounted. Unless, you unmount it you can't use that property. However, you could use `componentDidUpdate` since it is called as soon as it receives props.

Read more on this [lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

Edit: maybe you could try returning the axios promise along with the data and use it.

```
// Component
async componentDidMount() {
     const { allowedEvcCards} = this.props;
     const data = await allowedEvcCards(id);
     // ... do something with data
}

// Action
export function allowedEvcCards(id) {

    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(allowedEvcCardsLoading());

        return axios.get(`${API_URL}/****/****/${id}/*****`, {
            headers: {
                // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log("Allowed EVC response ", res.data);
                if (res.data.success === true) {
                    dispatch(allowedEvcCardsSuccess(res.data));
                    return res.data;
                } else {
                    console.log("error");
                    // alert("error");
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: ```return res.data;```??

Comment: Yes return the data so it can be assigned to the data in the component.

Comment: OP is using redux

Comment: Yes, regardless, it may return a value